# Efficient way for printing only ag-grid data without pagination or any other content

Tags: javascript, printing, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to print only ag-grid data such as the print button in [Data-Table print](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html)

1-I tried ngx-print but it doesn't work with angular 8.

2- I tried the official way from [ag-grid-Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-for-print/)
But I think it's not an efficient way also its show pagination and another page content when you print.

I tried [print-This](https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/) plugin with angular by following below steps :

1- install it by [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/print-this)
2- invoke the .js file inside node angular.json (the file that contains all plugin that you want to use in the system)
but still, it couldn't recognize the **.printThis()** as a function  .

I don't know how could I print the only ag-grid data without another content of the page, Why there is no built-in function for ag-grid such as DataTable plugin ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

> 2- I tried the official way from ag-grid-Example But I think it's not
>   an efficient way also its show pagination and another page content
>   when you print.

But this is already an efficient and expected way to print all data (without grid pagination).

If you wanna hide something else (can't realize what do you mean by **`without another content of the page`**)- it would be required to pre-render this data (or at least prepare for browser-print method)

> UPDATE
>
> I checked `datatable` solution, and basically its exactly as I said, they just prepared function which is making `datatable` content on new `window` to isolate from everything else and then execute `print()` method.

Here is a [part of their code](https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.js) (just for understanding):

```
// Construct a table for printing
var html = '<table class="'+dt.table().node().className+'">';

if ( config.header ) {
    html += '<thead>'+ addRow( data.header, 'th' ) +'</thead>';
}

html += '<tbody>';
for ( var i=0, ien=data.body.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
    html += addRow( data.body[i], 'td' );
}
html += '</tbody>';

if ( config.footer && data.footer ) {
    html += '<tfoot>'+ addRow( data.footer, 'th' ) +'</tfoot>';
}
html += '</table>';

...

// Allow stylesheets time to load
var autoPrint = function () {
    if ( config.autoPrint ) {
        win.print(); // blocking - so close will not
        win.close(); // execute until this is done
    }
};
```

Also, I tried to play with `hiding elements` which is also possible but in that way it would be required to care about visibility and overlays.

Comment: no not efficient way why should I make the ag-grid without pagination to use the print feature? why should I make resize operation to print feature? my customer wanna pagination and print ?!! review Print feature in dataTable you will understand what I mean by effiecen way!

Comment: @un.spike this look like a comment, not an answer!

Comment: @un.spike if you tried the example in [this link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-for-print/) you will find the ag-grid already hasn't had pagination and when you print you will find the print button appeared in the print preview !!!

Comment: @user3189162
Yes, I got your problem that's why added details in an answer

Comment: @un.spike thank you for your help , but I've another inquiry, So the part of code that you attached where should I put? and does it keep the ag-grid style?

Comment: You should take care of grid-data preparation by urself and I've just shown how it works on `datatable` library

Comment: @un.spike no need I returned back to use Angular-DataTables